# Stop numbering blank lines in Visual Studio Code

Tags: ide, editor, visual-studio-code

How to make VS-Code just number lines which contain some code or comment?

Edit: Like this

[image: Like that]

Comment: Is this to improve your workflow, or make it visually better? Just curious, because I don't know if blank lines matter if you are using them to jump around in the code or jump to a line as reported by a broken test case, or present code on a large screen. IMHO, line no. 559 is not different from line no. 525.

Comment: It's just a personal preference. It looks visually more attractive to me that way.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such setting in Visual Studio code. You can only display them in absolute numbers, intervals, or relative distance to your cursor. More info [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings#_default-settings).

Comment: Thanks i already found this settings. Was hoping for a workaround or an extension.